Unable to get correct import for AlertDialog (Or deprecated import?)
I'm following a Room tutorial for Kotlin and (at about 40 minutes) I get the following error:

Below is my code (I checked it and it seems exactly how shown in the video)
@Composable
fun AddContactDialog(
    state: ContactState,
    onEvent: (ContactEvent) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    AlertDialog(
        modifier = modifier,
        onDismissRequest = {
            onEvent(ContactEvent.HideDialog)
        },
        title = { Text(text = "Add contact") },
        text = {
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ){
                TextField(
                    value = state.firstName,
                    onValueChange = {
                        onEvent(ContactEvent.SetFirstName(it))
                    },
                    placeholder = {
                        Text(text = "First Name")
                    }
                )
                TextField(
                        value = state.lastName,
                    onValueChange = {
                        onEvent(ContactEvent.SetLastName(it))
                    },
                    placeholder = {
                        Text(text = "Last Name")
                    }
                )
                TextField(
                    value = state.phoneNumber,
                    onValueChange = {
                        onEvent(ContactEvent.SetPhoneNumber(it))
                    },
                    placeholder = {
                        Text(text = "Phone Number")
                    }
                )
            }
        },
        buttons = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterEnd
            ){
                Button(onClick = {
                    onEvent(ContactEvent.SaveContact)
                }){
                    Text(text = "Save")
                }
            }
        }
    )
}

Here are my imports:
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.room.util.TableInfo
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp


androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog is not the correct import, AlertDialog is a composable and is imported like this:
import androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialog

There are now multiple AlertDialog composables available (one is deprecated), but none that matches the parameters you provided. The one you want needs a confirmButton parameter instead of the buttons parameter. Just rename the parameter accordingly and everything should work fine.

I've already tryed but I got another error: @Deprecated(message = "Use BasicAlertDialog instead", replaceWith = @ReplaceWith(expression = "BasicAlertDialog(onDismissRequest, modifier, properties, content)", imports = {})) @ExperimentalMaterial3Api @Composable public fun AlertDialog(     onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,     modifier: Modifier = Modifier,     properties: DialogProperties = DialogProperties(),     content: @Composable () -> Unit ): Unit Deprecated: Use BasicAlertDialog instead Replace with: BasicAlertDialog(onDismissRequest, modifier, properties, content)

Please verify that you use at least the parameters confirmButton and onDismissRequest. Then remove all other parameters (now it should work fine) and add them back one at a time until you get the deprecation warning again. The last parameter added is the culprit and must be fixed.

In the end I needed only to replace buttons with confirmButton. I didn't fully understand your answer at the first reading

You mean like what my answer already says in the last two sentences? :) -- "[...] needs a confirmButton parameter instead of the buttons parameter. Just rename the parameter [...]"

Yep... sorry for misunderstanding :)
